# SQL Syntax Error with WHERE Clause

Tags: sql

```
INSERT INTO Census_Demographics (median_rooms)
    VALUES ('8')
    WHERE match_code = 'G06000104002001';
```

Above statement is throwing the follow error and I haven't been able to figure it out.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check  the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for  the right syntax to
>   use near 'WHERE match_code =  'G06000104002001'' at line 1 Query is :
>   INSERT INTO  Census_Demographics (median_rooms) VALUES ('8') WHERE 
>   match_code = 'G06000104002001'; Error Code: 1064

Answer (score 1):

You probably intend `update`:

```
update Census_Demographics
    set median_rooms = 8 
    where match_code = 'G06000104002001';
```

Comment: Wow, that's 2 `INSERT` / `UPDATE` questions answered in as many minutes. Makes me feel like somebody is running a class and hasn't given their students enough information when this happens :)

Comment: @Phil . . . One was for Postgres and one for MariaDB.  It would seem odd that they come from the same class.